# bash completion on empty (blank) command

Tags: bash, completion

On MSYS2 on my Windows machine, I have to switch to `bash` because `tcsh` is flaky and after an hour of messing around with completion scripts, .bashrc and .inputrc, I have almost got `bash` to behave in a way I am used to. However, there's one piece missing.

In `tcsh`, I could list the current directory on a single TAB press (i.e., a blank command). I am sure there's a way to do this in `bash` with the `complete -E` option, but I can find no examples.

Any help is appreciated!

Regards

Answer (score 5):

This will do what you want:

```
complete -Ef
```

Now try `<tab><tab>`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get what I wanted with this:

```
_listall () 
{
    COMPREPLY+=( $( ls ./))
}
complete -F _listall -E
```

Comment: This won't work as expected for filenames containing whitespace or certain names contains glob meta characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to declare a function, use:

```
function _bash_empty() {
    COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f --) ) ;
} ; complete -F '_bash_empty' -E ;
```

Still don't know what the `-E` parameter does. :)